# Stopping an asychronous loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have an asynchronous function that runs in a loop. It should run indefinitely unless one of the inner async functions rejects or the application is terminated. It should not impact the rest of the application.

```js
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

let executing = true;

const example = async () => {
  while (executing) {
    await setTimeout(1000);
    await someOtherFunc();
    await yetAnotherFunc();
  }
}
```

In my code I execute it without awaiting (since that blocks further execution). Later, I stop the loop by changing the value.

```js
const main = async () => {
  // don't await 
  example();
   
  // ... do stuff 'in parallel' to the asynchronous loop

  // possibly weeks later, elsewhere in the code
  executing = false;
}

main().then();
```

(Emphasis that the examples are contrived for Stack Overflow.)

It works, but it feels like a bit of a hack. Testing the execution/stop logic is tricky because the loop logic executes without the remaining test logic waiting. I need to mock the contents of the loop (the various async functions) for testing but because the test continues to execute without awaiting, the test later resets the mocks and the inner loop logic then tries to make unmocked calls.

What is the idiomatic way of achieving this in javascript / nodejs? I feel like a callback would allow me to keep using promises but I can't quite figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: "I need to mock the contents of the loop for testing but because the test continues to execute without awaiting" — Sounds like you should be mocking the `await`ed functions instead.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I am mocking the async calls inside the loop. I updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // don't await
> ```

There's the problem. Your `main` function definitely should wait until the loop has completed before returning (fulfilling its promise) to its caller.

You can achieve that by

```
async function main() {
  const promise = example();
   
  // ... do stuff

  executing = false;
  await promise;
}
```

or better (with proper error handling)

```
async function stuff() {
  // ... do stuff
  executing = false;
}
async function main() {
  await Promise.all([example(), stuff()];
}
```

Btw you probably shouldn't have a global `executing` variable. Better have one per call to `example()`, so that you can stop each running loop individually. Pass a mutable token object as an argument for that.